# Boost ASIO IPv6 multicast example error on MacOS: Can't assign requested address

Tags: c++, boost, udp, ipv6, multicast

I am having trouble running the multicast example from the Boost ASIO library on MacOS. If I run the example for IPv6 as suggested in the code itself, then I get the following error:

```
./receiver 0::0 ff31::8000:1234
Exception: set_option: Can't assign requested address
```

While using IPv4 addresses as suggested in the code works as intended.

I am using similar code already on Windows and Linux and it works just fine. Now that I'm compiling the code on MacOS it breaks in the same way as the official example code. The line that throws the exception is this one:

```
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));
```

I cannot get my head around why it fails.

The simplified example code ([original source from boost.org](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/multicast/receiver.cpp)) is as follows:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class receiver
{
public:
  receiver(boost::asio::io_context &io_context,
          const boost::asio::ip::address &listen_address,
          const boost::asio::ip::address &multicast_address)
      : socket_(io_context)
  {
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(listen_address, 30001);
    socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
    socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

    // === THE FOLLOWING LINE FAILS ===
    socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));
  }

private:
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: receiver <listen_address> <multicast_address>\n";
      std::cerr << "  For IPv4, try:\n";
      std::cerr << "    receiver 0.0.0.0 239.255.0.1\n";
      std::cerr << "  For IPv6, try:\n";
      std::cerr << "    receiver 0::0 ff31::8000:1234\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    receiver r(io_context,
              boost::asio::ip::make_address(argv[1]),
              boost::asio::ip::make_address(argv[2]));
    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception &e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My machine has a whole bunch of network interfaces (some from installing VirtualBox I guess) and I'm wondering if it has something to do with that (MAC addresses replaced):

```
ifconfig

lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC1: flags=0<> mtu 0
XHC0: flags=0<> mtu 0
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
VHC128: flags=0<> mtu 0
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    inet6 fe80::18ae:f381:4c4c:62e6%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xa
    inet 192.168.43.242 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.43.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    inet6 fe80::2483:b4ff:fec9:2590%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 13 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 14 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 15 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 16 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::2f34:55e7:4eee:9260%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Comment: Well, you are actually using an invalid multicast address: "_FF3X::0:0-FF3X::3FFF:FFFF Invalid addresses [[RFC4607](http://www.iana.org/go/rfc4607)]_"` You cannot simply make up IPv6 multicast addresses. There are flags and scopes to consider.

Comment: As far as I can tell, FF31::8000:1234 is not in the invalid range that you posted. This is also the address used in the official example code, so I am assuming it is correct. I have also played with other addresses but the result is the same.